# string analysis

Tags: c++, string

IF a string may include several un-necessary elements, e.g., such as @, #, $,%.

How to find them and delete them?

I know this requires a loop iteration, but I do not know how to represent sth such as @, #, $,%.

If you can give me a code example, then I will be really appreciated.

Comment: Since you are talking about a string, i'm gonna assume you mean C++, and will retag it as such.

Comment: A string means the same thing in C as well.

Comment: @James: I really don't think you can make that assumption.

Comment: @Android Eve: nothing is less true: `std::string != char*`

Comment: @Android Eve: Only to C programmers who hate C++ because it isn't C.

Comment: The important thing is that "string" has a meaning in C, whether or not it has the same meaning in C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual standard C++ approach would be the [erase/remove idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
struct OneOf {
        std::string chars;
        OneOf(const std::string& s) : chars(s) {}
        bool operator()(char c) const {
                return chars.find_first_of(c) != std::string::npos;
        }
};
int main()
{
    std::string s = "string with @, #, $, %";
    s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), OneOf("@#$%")), s.end());
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

and yes, boost offers some neat ways to write it shorter, for example using [boost::erase_all_regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/erase_all_regex.html)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
int main()
{
    std::string s = "string with @, #, $, %";
    erase_all_regex(s, boost::regex("[@#$%]"));
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get fancy, there is [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) otherwise you can use the [STL replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) function in combination with the [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/) function..

Answer (score 3):

And if you, for some reason, have to do it yourself C-style, something like this would work:

```
char* oldstr = ... something something dark side ...

int oldstrlen = strlen(oldstr)+1;
char* newstr = new char[oldstrlen]; // allocate memory for the new nicer string
char* p = newstr; // get a pointer to the beginning of the new string

for ( int i=0; i<oldstrlen; i++ ) // iterate over the original string
    if (oldstr[i] != '@' && oldstr[i] != '#' && etc....) // check that the current character is not a bad one
      *p++ = oldstr[i]; // append it to the new string
*p = 0; // dont forget the null-termination
```

Answer (score 3):

I think for this I'd use `std::remove_copy_if`:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct bad_char { 
    bool operator()(char ch) { 
        return ch == '@' || ch == '#' || ch == '$' || ch == '%';
    }
};

int main() { 
    std::string in("This@is#a$string%with@extra#stuff$to%ignore");
    std::string out;
    std::remove_copy_if(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), bad_char());
    std::cout << out << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Thisisastringwithextrastufftoignore
```

Since the data containing these unwanted characters will normally come from a file of some sort, it's also worth considering getting rid of them as you read the data from the file instead of reading the unwanted data into a string, and *then* filtering it out. To do this, you could create a facet that classifies the unwanted characters as white space:

```
struct filter: std::ctype<char> 
{
    filter(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::mask());

        rc['@'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['#'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['$'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['%'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

To use this, you imbue the input stream with a locale using this facet, and then read normally. For the moment I'll use an `istringstream`, though you'd normally use something like an `istream` or `ifstream`:

```
int main() { 
    std::istringstream in("This@is#a$string%with@extra#stuff$to%ignore");
    in.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new filter));

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(in), 
        std::istream_iterator<char>(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this C or C++? (You've tagged it both ways.)

In pure C, you pretty much have to loop through character by character and delete the unwanted ones. For example:

```
char *buf; 
int len = strlen(buf);
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (buf[i] == '@' || buf[i] == '#' || buf[i] == '$' /* etc */)
    {
        for (j = i; j < len; j++)
        { 
            buf[j] = buf[j+1];
        }
        i --;
    }
}
```

This isn't very efficient - it checks each character in turn and shuffles them all up if there's one you don't want. You have to decrement the index afterwards to make sure you check the new next character.

Answer (score 2):

General algorithm:

1. Build a string that contains the characters you want purged: "@#$%"
2. Iterate character by character over the subject string.
3. Search if each character is found in the purge set.
4. If a character matches, discard it.
5. If a character doesn't match, append it to a result string.

Depending on the string library you are using, there are functions/methods that implement one or more of the above steps, such as strchr() or find() to determine if a character is in a string.

Answer (score 1):

use the characterizer operator, ie `a` would be `'a'`. you haven't said whether your using C++ strings(in which case you can use the find and replace methods) or C strings in which case you'd use something like this(this is by no means the best way, but its a simple way):

```
void RemoveChar(char* szString, char c)
{
    while(*szString != '\0')
    {
        if(*szString == c)
            memcpy(szString,szString+1,strlen(szString+1)+1);

        szString++;
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, good catch, was thing of MSVC's preprocessor charizing operator(#@)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and call `find_last_of` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) repeatedly to find the last character that you want to replace, replace it with blank, and then continue working backwards in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do :

```
bool is_bad(char c)
{
  if( c == '@' || c == '#' || c == '$' || c == '%' )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  string str = "a #test #@string";
  str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), is_bad), str.end() );
}
```

If your compiler supports lambdas (or if you can use boost), it can be made even shorter. Example using boost::lambda :

```
  string str = "a #test #@string";
  str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), (_1 == '@' || _1 == '#' || _1 == '$' || _1 == '%')), str.end() );
```

(yay two lines!)

Answer (score -1):

A character is represented in C/C++ by single quotes, e.g. '@', '#', etc. (except for a few that need to be escaped).

To search for a character in a string, use strchr(). Here is a link to a sample code:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/

Comment: C/C++ is not a language, and they're not the same thing either.

Comment: A solution that works in C, works (usually) in C++ as well. The opposite is not true. The answer I provided suggests a solution that's **portable** across C *and* C++. Please avoid pettiness when the meaning of what's been written is clear.